# display which column error is coming from

Tags: asp.net

So im importing an excel doc using 'excel data reader' in my asp.net project,
if one of the columns are empty it throws an error

```
else
{ 
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("UOM column is empty at row");
}
```

how would I go about giving the exact column that is empty eg. 'row 77'

Comment: can you put your whole code for reading the document.

Comment: Well, I try to imagine the remainder of your code and give you an answer. Please, add the code!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this link
https://gist.github.com/924413/29bd3d648e5a3432387327e64cf1b93a0800bcf4

to read excel file then

```
  foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
          Console.Write("\"" + table.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + "\";");
          Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
```

then `i` is the row and `j` is the column.